# Locate a directory listing of an iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, deep-linking

I'm looking for a way to uncover directory paths in an iOS app, for the purposes of deep linking.

Right now, I know that I can unpack an app's info.plist file and look for the "CFBundleURLScheme." This parameter usually looks like this:

```
CFBundleURLTypes = (
    {   CFBundleURLName = "BUNDLEID";
        CFBundleURLSchemes = ( "scheme", "fb1234567891011" );
    },
);
```

From here, I can construct a basic URL scheme to launch the app to the home page, by appending "://" to the end of one of the "CFBundleURLSchemes."

If I enter `scheme://`
into Safari's URL bar and hit enter, then the app will launch on my iPhone to the app's homepage.

However, there is another deep link I know works - `scheme://upgrade/pro`- This links to a specific in-app directory, and when launched in Safari, opens the app directly to the upgrade page.

I want to be able to find a list of in-app directories that I can append to the basic URL scheme to be able to link to actual in-app pages.

Is there a file somewhere in an app's bundle or Payload folder that has a list of defined directory paths?

I hope that made sense, thanks in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

No. The URL goes to an entry-point in the app that is parsed by code.  Each app can do it how it wants.  It could just be a bunch of if/else statements.

Best bet is to ask the developer -- if they made these entry-points, they probably want people to know about them.

Comment: So there is no way to discover these entry points without consulting the developer?

Is there any way to even verify whether or not additional entry points are available?

Comment: How do you even know about this one?

Comment: By consulting the developer